# What am I supposed to do when coffee shop leave some coffee beans in my latte

Tags: beans

New comer here, the coffee house serve my latte with 3 or 4 coffee beans floating on the foam, what am I supposed to do with them? eat them? pick them out? or drink it and spit the beans out? Sorry for asking such embarassing question, I like instant coffee but I'm not so familiar with coffee house

Comment: Are these normal coffee beans or are they made of chocolate or sugar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should eat floating coffee beans, will add extra caffeine and also beneficial antioxidants and nutrition compared with just the drink. On average a coffee bean does contain 12mg of caffeine, adding that to your drink will not change flavor but will just increase overall caffeine content.

Is like chocolate-covered coffee beans treats, get enough caffeine from a snack.

> On average, eight coffee beans provide an equivalent amount of
>   caffeine as one cup of coffee. Your body absorbs caffeine from whole
>   coffee beans at a quicker rate than that from liquid coffee.

[coffee beans benefits](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/eating-coffee-beans#benefits)

Answer (score 3):

They are not harmful and as stated in the previous comment, can have health benefits, so it's totally up to you. You can always try eating one and if you don't like it either don't eat the other ones and leave them in your drink or just remove them and make sure you request not to have the beans on your drink next time. If you like it then you've discovered a cool, new thing that you like.